# Securing NextJS App with On-Behalf-Of Credential Flow in httponly cookie

Tags: reactjs, next.js, azure-ad-msal, next-auth

I'm developing an app in NextJS which will interface with Azure Storage Account Blobs and Azure DevOps. While developing I was authenticating to the Azure Blob Storage using `@azure/identity`, specifically the `ClientSecretCredential` which takes in the client ID, client secret and tenant ID; and authenticating to DevOps using a PAT. The app also uses the `next-auth` package for authentication into the app itself.

For production, I decided the best way would be to use the On-Behalf-Of Credential Flow to get a token with a scope of my NextJS app (as an app registration in AAD) and then further use that token to authenticate to the storage account:

```js
  const credential = new OnBehalfOfCredential({
    clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
    userAssertionToken: cookies['obo-token']
  })
```

I use `next-auth` to call the `AzureADProvider` then use a JWT callback to set a cookie for each On-Behalf-Of token scope defined in an array. This is what my code looks like:

```js
// Set an authority
const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}`

// Set scopes
const scopes = {
        "devops-token": "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation",
        "obo-token": "api://808f5b9e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c18d08f6cf18/custom.scope"
}

// Define MSAL config
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        authority,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        knownAuthorities: [authority],
    },
};

// Define confidential client app
const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

// Define get OBO token for scope
const acquireOBO = async (accessToken: string, scope: string) => {
        const token = await cca
            .acquireTokenOnBehalfOf({
                oboAssertion: accessToken,
                scopes: [scope],
            });

        return token?.accessToken
    };

// Set next-auth options
const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req, res) => {
    return {
        providers: [...],
        callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account }) {
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token;
            }
            await Promise.all(Object.entries(scopes).map(async ([key, scope]) => {
                await acquireOBO(token.accessToken as string, scope)
                .then((token) => {
                    const cookie = serialize(key, String(token), {
                        httpOnly: true,
                        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
                        sameSite: 'strict',
                        maxAge: 3600, 
                        path: '/',
                    });
                    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie);
                })
            }));
    
            return token;
        },
    },
...
```

So as mentioned, when a user authenticates into the app, the JWT callback is called, fetches an access token for each scope defined in `scopes` and sets a httponly cookie with that access token.

I have `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` env variable set which encodes the JWT tokens, but as I'm setting my own cookies I don't think it's used.

Is this best practice and is there anything I can do to make this more secure?